# Angularjs $rootScope:inprog error when implementing jquery click on input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am displaying a button which, when clicked locates an input element

```
 <input type="file" multiple style="display:none" />
```

Once the element is located (using jquery), I try to issue a click.  While this does work (the select files dialog opens), I also get a $rootScope:inprog error in angularjs.

My actual HTML looks like this

```
<div ng-controller="upload as vm">
<button ng-disabled="!vm.selectedUpload" ng-click="vm.addFilesClick()">
     Add Files
</button>

<table>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="up in vm.uploadList" ng-click="vm.selectUpload(up)">
          <td>
             <b>{{up.Name}}</b>
          </td>
          <td>
             <input id={{up.Id}} type="file" multiple="multiple" style="display:none" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().$parent.vm.filesChange(this)" />
          </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

And here is the controller:

```
(function() {
   'use strict';
   angular.module('upload.app').controller("upload",[upload]);

   function upload() {
      var me = this;
      me.uploadList = [];
      me.selectedUpload = null;
      ...
      me.addFilesClick = function(){
         var _element = $("#" + me.selectedUpload.Id);
         if(_element)
             _element.click();
       }
   }
 )();
```

Why am I getting this error and what can I do to correct it? Also, if someone knows of a better way of being able to force a click on an element without having to access the element in my controller, that would be helpful as well.

Comment: Usual ptactice in such case - make your file input invisible ( with opacity property by css ) and set his position so, that he get place over button. And when user click on button he in real click by input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject $timeout in the controller and use it to invoke click event as AngularJS allows only one $digest or $apply operation at a time.

```
if(_element) {
    $timeout(function() {
         _element.click();
     }, 1);
}
```